# MWG Exercise 2.E.5

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, consumer-theory, theory, decision-theory

### **Exercise**

> Suppose that $x(\mathbf{p},w)$ is a demand function which is homogeneous of degree one with respect to $w$ and satisfies Walras' law and homogeneity of degree zero. Suppose also that all the cross-price effects are zero, that is $\frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial p_k} = 0$ whenever $k \neq l$. Show that this implies that for every $l$, $x_l(\mathbf{p},w) = \frac{\alpha_lw}{p_l}$, where $\alpha_l > 0$ is a constant independent of $(\mathbf{p},w)$.

### **My Attempt**

This is how I proceed. (I got stuck in the end and couldn't manage to show that $\alpha_l$ is a constant independent of $(\mathbf{p},w)$.)

> By Proposition 2.E.2, since all the cross-price effects are zero, we have that
> \begin{align*}
> p_l\frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial p_l} + x_l(\mathbf{p},w) = 0,\ \text{for}\ l = 1,\dots,L.
> \end{align*}
> By Proposition 2.E.1, again since all the cross-price effects are zero, we have that
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial p_l}p_l + \frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial w}w = 0,\ \text{for}\ l = 1,\dots,L.
> \end{align*}
> Then,
> \begin{align*}
> x_l(\mathbf{p},w) = \frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial w}w,
> \end{align*}
> so that
> \begin{align*}
> x_l(\mathbf{p},w) = \frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial w}p_l \cdot \frac{w}{p_l}
> \end{align*}
> Let $\alpha_l = \frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial w}p_l$

From here, I don't know how to proceed next. Could someone please help me out? If we were to follow this method, how to show that the $\alpha_l$ is a constant independent of $(\mathbf{p},w)$?

### **Answer from the Solution Manual**

I looked up and find the following answer from the Solution Manual. However, I am confused by some of its steps.

> Since $x(\mathbf{p},w)$ is homogeneous of degree one with respect to $w$, $x(\mathbf{p},\alpha w) = \alpha x(\mathbf{p},w)$ for every $\alpha > 0$. Thus, $x_l(\mathbf{p},w) = wx_l(\mathbf{p},1)$. Since $\frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},1)}{\partial p_k} = \frac{\partial\varphi_l(p)}{\partial p_k} = 0$ whenever $k \neq l$, $x_l(\mathbf{p},1)$ is actually a function of $p_l$ alone. So we can write $x_l(\mathbf{p},w) =  x_l(p_l)$. Since $x(\mathbf{p},w)$ is homogeneous of degree zero, $x_l(p_l)$ must be homogeneous of degree $-1$ (in $p_l$). Hence, there exists $\alpha_l > 0$ such that $x_l(p_l) = \frac{\alpha_l}{p_l}$. By Walras' law, $\sum_{l}p_l\left(\frac{\alpha_l}{p_l}\right)w = w\sum_{l}\alpha_l = w$. We must thus have $\sum_l\alpha_l = 1$.

I start to feel confused after it said that "$x_l(\mathbf{p},1)$ is actually a function of $p_l$ alone.". For example, I do not think we can write $x_l(\mathbf{p},w) =  x_l(p_l)$; I cannot see how $x_l(p_l)$ must be homogeneous of degree $-1$ (in $p_l$); and the last sentence about applying Walras' law is definitely not right. Here is my understanding of this answer from the Solution Manual. I would like to know if it is correct.

> Since $x(\mathbf{p},w)$ is homogeneous of degree one with respect to $w$, $x(\mathbf{p},\alpha w) = \alpha x(\mathbf{p},w)$ for every $\alpha > 0$. Thus, $x_l(\mathbf{p},w) = wx_l(\mathbf{p},1)$. Since $\frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},1)}{\partial p_k} = \frac{\partial\varphi_l(p)}{\partial p_k} = 0$ whenever $k \neq l$, $x_l(\mathbf{p},1)$ is actually a function of $p_l$ alone. Thus, we can write $x_l(\mathbf{p},w) = x_l(p_l,w)$. Since $x(\mathbf{p},w)$ is homogeneous of degree zero and is homogeneous of degree one with respect to $w$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> x_l(\alpha p_l, w) &= x_l(p_1,\dots,\alpha p_l,\dots,p_L,w)\\
> &= x_l\left(\alpha \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\alpha}p_1,\dots,p_l,\dots,\frac{1}{\alpha}p_L,\frac{1}{\alpha}w\right)\right)\\
> &= x_l\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}p_1,\dots,p_l,\dots,\frac{1}{\alpha}p_L,\frac{1}{\alpha}w\right)\\
> &= x_l\left(p_l,\frac{1}{\alpha}w\right)\\
> &= \frac{1}{\alpha}x_l(p_l,w).
> \end{align*}
> Therefore, $x_l(p_l,w)$ is homogeneous of degree $-1$ with respect to $p_l$. Hence,
> \begin{align*}
> x_l(\mathbf{p},w) &= x_l(p_1,\dots,p_l,\dots,p_L,w)\\
> &= \frac{1}{p_l}x_l(p_1,\dots,1,\dots,p_L,w)\\
> &= \frac{w}{p_l}x_l(p_1,\dots,1,\dots,p_L,1).
> \end{align*}
> Let $\alpha_l = x_l(p_1,\dots,1,\dots,p_L,1)$. Since $x_l$ is independent of $p_k$ for all $k \neq l$, we have that $\alpha_l$ is a constant independent of $(\mathbf{p},w)$.

### **My Questions**

So, as I have mentioned earlier, I have two questions:

1. If we were to follow my method (in the My Attempt section), is it possible for us to proceed to show that $\frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial w}p_l$ is a constant independent of $(\mathbf{p},w)$?
2. I feel that the answer in the Solution Manual is not correct, and I provided my understanding of his method. I would like to know whether my understanding of the answer from the Solution Manual is correct or not?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The proof given in the Solution Manual is correct, except the typo in the equation at the end of line 3, which should read $x_l(\mathbf{p},w) =  x_l(p_l)w$.
Then, because $x_l(\mathbf{p},w)$ is homogeneous of degree zero in $(\mathbf{p},w)$, it implies that $x_l(p_l)w$ is homogeneous of degree zero in $(p_l,w)$, which in turn implies that $x_l(p_l)$ must be homogeneous of degree $-1$ in $p_l$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to 1.**

> $$ x_l(\mathbf{p},w) = \frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial w}p_l \cdot \frac{w}{p_l} $$
> Let $\alpha_l = \frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial w}p_l$.

This is nice, now use the homogeneity properties.

**Answer to 2.**

Could do solution manual be wrong? A quick non conclusive trial:

For a Cobb-Douglas type function (where the cross price effects will be zero) $U(x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2$ the Marshallian demands are
$$
\begin{align*}
x_1(p_1,p_2,w) & = \frac{1}{2} \frac{w}{p_1} \\
x_2(p_1,p_2,w) & = \frac{1}{2} \frac{w}{p_2}.
\end{align*}
$$
The function $x_1(p_1,p_2,w)$ indeed

1. is homogenous of degree 0,
2. is homogenous of degree 1 w.r.t. $w$, i.e.
   $$
   x_1(p_1,p_2,w) = w \cdot x_1(p_1,p_2,1),
   $$
3. does not depend on $p_2$, we could write
   $$
   x_1(p_1) \triangleq x_1(p_1,p_2,1).
   $$

Furthermore, it is possible to write
$$
\begin{align*}
x_1(p_1,p_2,w) & = w \cdot x_1(p_1) = w \cdot \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{p_1} \\
x_1(p_1,p_2,w) & = w \cdot x_2(p_2) = w \cdot \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{p_2},
\end{align*}
$$
and then the alphas do indeed sum up to $1$. Though this was only one case (and a special one at that) the solution manual could be - and I think is - correct.

---

The root of the misunderstanding seems to be in this line:

> For example, I do not think we can write $x_l(\mathbf{p},w) =  x_l(p_l)$;

You are correct, this is not possible; but it is also not the claim. The claim

> $x_l(\mathbf{p},1)$ is actually a function of $p_l$ alone.

is not about the general range of the function $x_l$. First they restrict $w$ to $1$, thus they are only looking at the cases where $x_l(\mathbf{p},1)$. Then they explain that because there are no cross price effects (silent assumptions are made about integrability), changes in the other prices do not affect $x_l(\mathbf{p},1)$.

E.g. looking at $x_1(p_1,p_2,w)$ again
$$
x_1(p_1,20,w) - x_1(p_1,10,w) =
\int_{p_2 = 10}^{20} \frac{\partial x_1(p_1,p_2,w)}{\partial p_2} \text{d} p_2
$$
and by the no cross price effect assumption
$$
\frac{\partial x_1(p_1,p_2,w)}{\partial p_2} = 0
$$
so the whole thing is zero, $x_1(p_1,p_2,w)$ is not affected by any change in $p_2$.

So $x_l(\mathbf{p},w)$ is homogeneous of degree 1 w.r.t. $w$, is not affected by the prices $p_k$ where $p_k \neq p_l$. We also know that the general function is homogeneous of degree 0. This is only possible if changes in $p_l$ counter the effects of the changes in $w$. It is shown via the solution manual's calculation that this in fact means that $x_l(\mathbf{p},w)$ is homogeneous of degree $-1$ w.r.t $p_l$.

For the two good case the equation is, essentially, $\forall \alpha>0$:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_1(p_1,p_2,w) & = & x_1(\alpha \cdot p_1,\alpha \cdot p_2, \alpha \cdot w) \tag{hom. of deg. 0}
\\ \\
& = & \alpha \cdot x_1(\alpha \cdot p_1,\alpha \cdot p_2, w) \tag{hom. of deg. 1 w.r.t $w$}
\\ \\
& = & \alpha \cdot x_1(\alpha \cdot p_1, p_2, w) \tag{$p_2$ has no effect}
\\ \\
\alpha^{-1} \cdot x_1(p_1,p_2,w) & = & x_1(\alpha \cdot p_1, p_2, w) \tag{division by $\alpha$}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
This is the definition of $x_1$ being homogeneous of degree $-1$ w.r.t. $p_1$.

Comment: I found a dozen typos before going to bed, I feel confident that there are more; feel free to edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. For your "Answer to 1", here is my attempt: Since $x(\mathbf{p},w)$ is homogeneous of degree 1 in $w$, we have $\alpha_l=\frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial w}p_l=\frac{\partial(wx_l(\mathbf{p},1))}{\partial w}p_l=x_l(\mathbf{p},1)p_l$. Well, this indeed shows that $\alpha_l$ is independent of $w$, but why is it independent of $\mathbf{p}$ as well?

Comment: For your "Answer to 2", I still cannot understand how to derive $x_l(p_l)$ is homogeneous of degree $-1$ in the context of the answer from the Solution Manual. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: Can you please give the definition of $x_1(p_1)$ as you understand it and do you understand what I wrote otherwise?

Comment: "*$\alpha_l$ is independent of $w$, but why is it independent of $\mathbb{p}$ as well?*" How about using the homogeneity property that includes both variables, not just $w$?

Comment: As for "Answer to 1", do you mean the following: We have had $\alpha_l=\frac{\partial x_l(\mathbf{p},w)}{\partial w}p_l=x_l(\mathbf{p},1)p_l=x_l(p_l,1)p_l$, where the last equality comes from the fact that there is no cross-price effect. Since $x_l(\mathbf{p},w)=x_l(p_l,w)$ is homogeneous of degree 1 in $w$, we have $\alpha=x_l(p_l,1)p_l=x_l(p_l,p_l)=x_l(1,1)$, where the last equality holds because $x_l(\mathbf{p},w)=x_l(p_l,w)$ is homogeneous of degree 0. Therefore, $\alpha$ is a constant independent of $(\mathbf{p},w)$.

Comment: As for deriving $x_l(p_l)$ is homogeneous of degree $-1$ in your "Answer to 2", do you mean the following: The $x_l(p_l)$ in the Solution Manual should have been written as $x_l(p_l,1)$. Let $k\in\mathbb{R}_+$. Since, by the homogeneity of degree 0 and the homogeneity of degree 1 in $w$, $x_l(kp_l,1)=x_l(p_l,\frac{1}{k})=\frac{1}{k}x_l(p_l,1)$, we obtain that $x_l(p_l,1)$ is homogeneous of degree $-1$ in $p_l$. Basically, the effect of a $k$-percentage change in $p_l$ should offset the effect of a same $k$-percentage change in $w$, in order to make the demand function homogeneous of degree 0.

Comment: This is all correct except for "*in the Solution Manual should have been written*" because their current notation is also fine. They explicitly explain that they are introducing new notation. You don't have to like their notation, other people might, but the notation is defined, and the properties given for it are correct.